# Leverage browser caching issue on PHP with fastcgi module

Tags: php, google-pagespeed

My website is running on PHP which is using `fastcgi` module. There is Leverage browser caching issue in google `pagespeed` while `mod_expire` module enable on server. I have used below code in `htaccess` but it is not working.

```
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/gif "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/png "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType text/css "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/html "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/pdf "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/x-javascript "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access 1 year"
ExpiresDefault "access 1 month"
</IfModule>
```

I have asked to server guy and he replied

> "Because you're running the site on php which is running as a 'fastcgi
>   module', its not possible to set these values via htaccess."

How I can remove Leverage browser caching issue for js, css and images without `.htaccess`

Comment: If your `.htaccess` file is being ignored completely you'll need to make sure `AllowOverride` is enabled in `httpd.conf`.

Comment: .htaccess is working fine but mod_expire not working in htaccess.

Comment: Can you confirm that mod_expires is enabled?

Comment: Hi lan, thanks for reply. I have already mentioned that `mod_expire` is enable. Please see server guy reply.